How to make DAG running past midnight look at last 3 days of data?
I have a DAG running overnight where I need to run a python function on the past 3 days of data.
My schedule interval is 0 22 * * * and my start_date is pendulum.today(tz='America/Los_Angeles').subtract(days=1)
I pass pendulum.today(tz='America/Los_Angeles).subtract(days=3) as a parameter to my function. One issue I have is sometimes the dag runs past midnight, and when this task runs it is sometimes the next day, causing me to pass the wrong date. How can I ensure I pass a date anchored to when the dag started rather than at time of evaluation?

Airflow passes lot of parameters to the task via context. If you use versions lower than Airflow 2.0 you need to pass the parameter provide_context=True to the dag if not is pass by default, you just need to add **kwargs to the function.
Here is an example:
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import timedelta

def my_task(**kwargs):
    execution_date = kwargs.get('execution_date')
    print(f'The execution date is {execution_date}')
    three_days_ago = execution_date - timedelta(days=3)
    print(f'The date 3 days ago is {three_days_ago}')

my_python_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='example_task',
    python_callable=my_task,
    provide_context=True  # No need if your Airflow is higher than 2.0
)

